# Search for strings with multiple {tokens} in database

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table with messages. Some of them have one or more labels of the form `{bar|***}` with `***` being anything (letters, numbers, punctuation).

```
id  message
---------------------------------------------------
1   foo {bar|112} baz {bar|foo} {bar|215.54}
2   lorem ipsum {bar|foo} dolor {bar|samet} digitas
3   last {bar|t} label example
4   string with no label
5   another {zoo} string with {foo|ads} label
```

If I want to look for all messages with at least one label of the form {bar|***} I query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message LIKE '%{bar|%';
```

But now, I need a query with which I can select only those messages which have **at most** two such labels:

```
id  message
---------------------------------------------------
2   lorem ipsum {bar|foo} dolor {bar|samet} digitas
3   last {bar|t} label example
```

In other words: is there a way (in MySQL) to count the number of labels in a message and return only messages which have one or two labels in them?

Comment: you could do it with nested indexof calls and asserting the 3rd indested call returns -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (LENGTH(message) - LENGTH(REPLACE(message,'{bar|','')))/5 BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

This should work.